# How do I prevent two align to bottom controls from reversing order?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, vcl

I have a form with three main components:

1. A FlowPanel that is set to Align to Client
2. A second FlowPanel set to Align to Bottom
3. A StatusBar set to Align to Bottom.

Everything starts out looking great.  But the FlowPanel that is aligned to the bottom is also set to AutoSize.  It contains a panel that can collapse itself.  The internal panel contains summary information that the user can decide to hide.  This drops the size of the FlowPanel to a very small size but not completely gone.  There is still a button where the user can re-expand the summary panel.

The problem comes when the panel is re-expanded causing the FlowPanel to grow.  At that time the order of the Status Bar and the FlowPanel is reversed.  They are both still set to align bottom but now the status bar is above my FlowPanel.

I can duplicate this in a test app without the Collapsing panel just by putting button on the form to see the bottom flow panel's height.  If the height is increased the order changes.  If it is decreased then everything stays in the same order.  The only code in my test form is:

```
FlowPanel2.Height := FlowPanel2.Height * 2;
```

I also tested this with the bottom panel being a regular TPanel instead of a FlowPanel with the same results.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to prevent it?

[image: Moving Status bar image]

Comment: A fairly well-known and irritating quirck of alignment and autosize interaction. Add an OnResize event handler in which you set the status bar's top to the height of the container + 1, or the top+height of the panel it should follow. (looking at LOLCats, so a comment and not an answer).

Comment: @Mark: Hey, you've **my** hat on! :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Solution:

1. Place a Statusbar on form and align to Bottom
2. Place a Panel (Container_Panel) on form and align to Client
3. Place a FlowPanel on Container_Panel and align to Bottom
4. Place a FlowPanel on Container_Panel and align to Client

Now you should have no problems with that anymore

Comment: Another option that eliminates the need for `Container_Panel` is to use `Align=alCustom` to implement custom alignment. But for versions that do not support `alClient`, or you just don't want to write any code for it, then the `Container_Panel` approach works fine, at the cost of using an extra `HWND` handle.

Answer (score 8):

I sometimes have this too. My solution is to set Top of the control that shall be at the bottom to a "big enough" value - something like `OtherControl.Top + OtherControl.Height + 1` should work or even `MaxInt` IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to spend some money, I would recommend using DevExpress' [ExpreeLayoutControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExLayoutControl/) (or something similar). It's an excellent tool for both simple and complex forms, and in addition to solving troublesome quirks like the issue you are experiencing, it offers a host of other benefits.

Comment: -1. This is not an answer to the question. It's at best a comment suggesting a commercial component set as an alternative. (It would be fine as additional information *after* your answer, but as stand-alone content it isn't an answer.)

Comment: @KenWhite: I agree, and I was in doubt if I should post it as an answer. It would, as you say, fit better as a comment. But I decided to post it all the same, since it is a good solution to Mark Elders' _problem_, even though it's not an answer to his _question_.

Comment: @KenWhite One way to do this is to be less harsh. Less BOFH, if you will.

Comment: @KenWhite And yes, you are a moderator, in terms of having privileges to vote for the closing of questions. A privilege that you seem to use pretty often...

Comment: @KenWhite Yes it's advice, and it's your choice whether you want to take any of it to heart, or not. :)